# Is it correct to say "aging X years or more"?

Tags: word-usage

> Hundred participants (**aging 18 years or more**) were selected from
>   each of the  cities.

Is the phrase within the parentheses correct? Any suggestion to better express the idea will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditto Cornbread.

"Aging" refers to either (a) as a verb or gerund, the process, or (b) as an adjective, the state of being old.

An example of (a) would be the common idiom, "Sally is aging very gracefully", meaning that while she is no longer young, she looks good for her age. Or more pragmatically, "Aging often comes with many medical problems."

An example of (b) would be, "Our nursing home provides a variety of services to aging individuals." It's generally consider something of a euphemism for "old" -- you're not old yet, you're just aging.

Answer (score 10):

They are already there, so you'd want to call them *aged*.  Additionally, I would say *older* instead of *more*.  You could also leave out *years*.

> (one?) Hundred participants (aged 18 years or older) were selected
>   from each of the cities.

Comment: Your *aged nn or **older*** looks odd to me, so I checked Google Books. It seems out that's almost exclusively an American form - Brits invariably use [aged 18 or **over**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aged+18+or+over%2Caged+18+or+older&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3)

Comment: How about "18 years and aging"? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, we use *or over* as well, but in my recollection it mostly occurs in fine print.  *Entrants aged 21 or over.  Offer may vary in Alaska and Hawaii.  See store for details.  Void where prohibited.*

Comment: @JeffSahol, I like it.

Comment: What does "They are already there" mean?

Comment: They have reached the given minimum age of 18.

Answer (score -2):

"Hundred participants (scoring 18 points or more) ..." sounds fine to me. This is actually how sentences are generally structured in 'papers'.

Standard structure and semantics score over strict grammar here.

Comment: They are of the same structure, aren't they. Any applicable word may appear in place of "scoring" depending on the case. I expected that would be obvious.

Comment: @Jasper Please read the answer again. And my comment above.

Comment: Actually I also saw in papers what @Kris has suggested. That is why I was in doubt.